# How to make <input> value flexible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two ReactJS components, the first one will display a grid.  When a row is clicked, it will populate the 2 component with Name.

But when I try to edit the input box, it cannot be changed.  What are the proper way in ReactJS to handle this.

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { formName : ''}
        this.handleFormName = this.handleFormName.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleFormName(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
        this.setState({ formName: e.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log(this.state.formName);
        axios.post(this.props.UrlPost, { FirstName: this.state.formName })
          .then(function (response) {
          });
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
            Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.props.Name}  onChange={this.handleFormName} />
        </label>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
        }
}

class ComponentWithGriddle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedRowId: 0,
        };
    }
    onRowClick(row) {
        console.log(row.props.data.name);
        this.setState({ selectedRowId: row.props.data.id });
        this.props.handleNameChange(row.props.data.name);
    }
    render() {
        var rowMetadata = {bodyCssClassName: rowData => (rowData.id === this.state.selectedRowId ? "selected" : '')};
        //console.log(rowMetadata);
        return (
        <Griddle results={fakeData} onRowClick={this.onRowClick.bind(this)} columnMetadata={columnMeta} useFixedHeader={true} rowMetadata={rowMetadata} useGriddleStyles={true} />
        );
     }
}

class RootFrame extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
        this.state = { Name: '' };
    }

    handleNameChange(name)
    {
        this.setState({ Name: name });
    }
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <ComponentWithGriddle Name={this.state.Name} handleNameChange={this.handleNameChange} />
            <NameForm UrlPost={this.props.UrlPost}  Name={this.state.Name}/>
        </div>
       );
    };
}


var emptyData = [];

var columnMeta = [
  {
      "columnName": "id",
      "order": 1,
      "locked": false,
      "visible": true,
      "displayName": "ID"
  },
  {
      "columnName": "name",
      "order": 2,
      "locked": false,
      "visible": true,
      "displayName": "Name"
  },
  {
      "columnName": "city",
      "order": 3,
      "locked": false,
      "visible": true
  },
  {
      "columnName": "state",
      "order": 4,
      "locked": false,
      "visible": true
  },
  {
      "columnName": "country",
      "order": 5,
      "locked": false,
      "visible": true
  },
  {
      "columnName": "company",
      "order": 6,
      "locked": false,
      "visible": true
  },
  {
      "columnName": "favoriteNumber",
      "order": 7,
      "locked": false,
      "visible": true,
      "displayName": "Favorite Number"
  }
];

var rowMeta =
{
    "key": "id"
};

var propertyGridMeta = [
  {
      "columnName": "property",
      "order": 1,
      "locked": false,
      "visible": true,
      "cssClassName": "properties-name",
      "displayName": "Property"
  },
  {
      "columnName": "description",
      "order": 2,
      "locked": false,
      "visible": true,
      "cssClassName": "properties-description",
      "displayName": "Description"
  },
  {
      "columnName": "type",
      "order": 3,
      "locked": false,
      "visible": true,
      "cssClassName": "properties-type",
      "displayName": "Type"
  },
  {
      "columnName": "default",
      "order": 4,
      "locked": false,
      "visible": true,
      "cssClassName": "properties-default",
      "displayName": "Default"
  }
]

var fakeData = [
  {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Mayer Leonard",
      "city": "Kapowsin",
      "state": "Hawaii",
      "country": "United Kingdom",
      "company": "Ovolo",
      "favoriteNumber": 7
  },
  {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Koch Becker",
      "city": "Johnsonburg",
      "state": "New Jersey",
      "country": "Madagascar",
      "company": "Eventage",
      "favoriteNumber": 2
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Lowery Hopkins",
      "city": "Blanco",
      "state": "Arizona",
      "country": "Ukraine",
      "company": "Comtext",
      "favoriteNumber": 3
  },
];



ReactDOM.render(<RootFrame UrlPost={'Home/SaveData'}/>,
        document.getElementById("demoForm"));
```

Essentially, I am trying to select a row, at the same time be able to change the name and click submit.

Selected row from grid

From the "Name" field,  user can change the name.

Answer (score 0):

Your input doesnt work because you are setting a static value `this.props.Name` for the input. In order to edit your input and still set the initial value with `this.props.Name` you should make use of state

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { formName : '', inputName: ''}
        this.handleFormName = this.handleFormName.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({inputName: this.props.Name});
    }
    handleFormName(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
        this.setState({ formName: e.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log(this.state.formName);
        this.setState({inputName: event.target.value});
        axios.post(this.props.UrlPost, { FirstName: this.state.formName })
          .then(function (response) {
          });
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
            Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.inputName}  onChange={this.handleFormName.bind(this)} />
        </label>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
        }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to select a row, and populate the text input with the Name from the selected row.   At the same time I can change the name in the text input.  How to achieve this,  yet setting a static field from the grid row and allow the user to modify the selected value.

Comment: Any time you want to update the value of the input, you can just update the state and the new value will reflect in the input. Thats the advantage of using controlled input. You can even change the value yourself by entering the data